# How do only search view in odoo

Tags: odoo-8

I need only search view and remove save button.

If you search and bring the necessary data, but I need not to show the save and new button, that is, it only allows me to consult according to the selected client.

I try the next:
This function search and then set values in fields.

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def _onchange_partner_id(self):
    """Método que busca el número de CI o Ruc digitado para cargar datos automaticamente"""
    if self.partner_id:
        contract_id = self.env['plan.partner.contract'].search([('partner_id', '=', self.partner_id.id)])

        if contract_id:
            for record in contract_id:
                car_ids = self.env['plan.car'].search([('contract_id','=',record.id)])
                self.contract_id = record.id 
                self.partner_ruc_id = record.partner_ruc_id 
                self.number_paid_fees = record.number_paid_fees 
                self.number_pending_fees = record.number_pending_fees 
                self.number_future_fees = record.number_future_fees 
                self.paid_amount = record.paid_amount 
                self.anticipated_amount = record.anticipated_amount 
                self.pending_amount = record.pending_amount 
                self.partial_amount = record.partial_amount 
                self.number_partial_fees = record.number_partial_fees 
                self.partial_amount_a = record.partial_amount_a 
                self.number_partial_a_fees = record.number_partial_a_fees
                self.plan_car_id = car_ids
        else:
            raise Warning(_(
                        "Identification Number does not exist"))
```

The current view is:
[image: current_search]

I need on this view, only search by partner_id and remove the save button
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my requirement:
I use wizard, for only search:
Python code:

```
class plan_web_wallet_wizard(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = 'plan.web.wallet.wizard'
    _description = 'Web Wallet Wizard'
    contract_id = fields.Many2one('plan.partner.contract', 'Plan Partner', Contract')
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner',related='contract_id.partner_id')  

    plan_car_id = fields.One2many('plan.car', 
    related='contract_id.schedule_pay_ids')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('partner_id', 'ident_num')
    def count_bidding_1(self):
        bidding_obj = self.env['plan.bidding']
        for record in self:
            bidding_id = bidding_obj.search([('contract_id', '=', record.contract_id.id)])
            if bidding_id:
                self.count_bidding = len(bidding_id)

    @api.onchange('partner_id')
    def onchange_partner_id(self):
        contract_obj = self.env['plan.partner.contract']
        for record in self:
            contract_id = contract_obj.search([('partner_id', '=', record.partner_id.id)])
            if contract_id:
                for contract in contract_id:
                    self.contract_id = contract.id
                    contract.calculate_summary()

    @api.onchange('ident_num')
    def onchange_ident_num(self):
        contract_obj = self.env['plan.partner.contract']
        for record in self:
            contract_id = contract_obj.search([('ident_num', '=', record.ident_num)])
            if contract_id:
                for contract in contract_id:
                    self.contract_id = contract.id
```

XML file:

```
<form string="wallet" name="wallet">
<sheet name="web_wallet" string="Web Wallet">
    <h1 class="text-center" name="wellcome">
        <label string="Wellcome Web Wallet"/>
    </h1>
    <br/>
    <group name="search_contract" col="4">
        <field name="partner_id" string="Customer" options="{'no_create_edit': True, 'no_open':True}"
               domain="[('customer','=',1),('partner_state','=','adherent')]"/>
        <field name="ident_num" string="RUC/CC" placeholder="Search identification number"/>
        <field name="contract_id" string="Contract" domain="[('ident_num','=',ident_num)]"
               options="{'no_create_edit': True, 'no_open':True}"/>
    </group>
    <notebook name="web_wallet">
        <page name="contract_summary" string="Contract Summary">
            <h1 name="string" class="text-center">
                <label string="Contract Summary"/>
            </h1>
        </page>
        <page name="web_paids" string="Contract Paids">
            <h1 name="string" class="text-center">
                <label string="Pagos Programados"/>
            </h1>
            <group name="paids">
                <field name="plan_car_id" mode="tree" nolabel="1" readonly="1">
                    <tree string="List Paid Quotas" editable="false" readonly="1"
                          colors="blue:state=='draft';black:state=='done';gray:state=='cancel'">
                        <field readonly="1" name="plan_payment_number"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="date_to"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="name"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="state"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="contract_id"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="partner_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="inscription_quota" sum="Inscription" string="C.Ins."/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="capital_quota" sum="Capital" string="C.Cap."/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="administrative_quota" sum="Administrative" string="C.Adm."/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="monthly_quota" sum="Monthly" string="C.Mensual"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="total_iva" sum="IVA" string="IVA"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="total_quota" sum="Total" string="Total"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="pay_type"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field readonly="1" name="plan_run_id" invisible="1"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </group>
        </page>
    </notebook>
</sheet>
<footer>
    <button special="cancel" string="Cerrar" class="oe_link"/>
</footer>
</form>
```

Image this view:
[image: Only search view]